# I have a table and if A2> A1 in the table, I want to set the row to red color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I want to compare it to the table.

If `A2 > A1`, I want to set the row to **red** color.
I can access data with Each command, but I have difficulty in the class to assign.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-4" style="font-size: 12px; ">
  <thead>
    <th>
      <center>Stok</center>
    </th>
    <th>
      <center>A1</center>
    </th>
    <th>
      <center>A2</center>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="arsivTablosu">

    <tr id="satir">
      <td>A1</td>
      <td id="envanter" class="">
        <center>44</center>
      </td>
      <td id="kritikStok" class="">
        <center>45</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="satir">
      <td>A2</td>
      <td id="envanter" class="">
        <center>50</center>
      </td>
      <td id="kritikStok" class="">
        <center>10</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="satir">
      <td>A3</td>
      <td id="envanter" class="">
        <center>26</center>
      </td>
      <td id="kritikStok" class="">
        <center>27</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="satir">
      <td>A4</td>
      <td id="envanter" class="">
        <center>40</center>
      </td>
      <td id="kritikStok" class="">
        <center>39</center>
      </td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `id="satir"`. An ID must be unique. Use `class="satir"` instead.

Comment: Table create via php code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your tbody trs then use `.find("td:eq(1) center")` to get value of td from 2nd column and `.find("td:eq(2) center")` to get value from 3rd column then compare both and add class depending on this .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//loop through tr
$("#arsivTablosu tr").each(function() {
  //check the value of 2 & 3 td 
  parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(2) center").text()) > parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(1) center").text()) ? $(this).addClass("red_color") : ""
})
```

```css
.red_color {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-4" style="font-size: 12px; ">
  <thead>
    <th>
      <center>Stok</center>
    </th>
    <th>
      <center>A1</center>
    </th>
    <th>
      <center>A2</center>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="arsivTablosu">

    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>
        <center>44</center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>45</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>
        <center>50</center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>10</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>
        <center>26</center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>27</center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>A4</td>
      <td>
        <center>40</center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>39</center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: HI, if anyone answer help you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking on tick symbol .